# top_n versus order in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble understanding the output from dplyr's top_n function. Can anybody help?

```
n=10

df = data.frame(ref=sample(letters,n),score=rnorm(n))

require(dplyr)

print(dplyr::top_n(df,5,score))

print(df[order(df$score,decreasing = T)[1:5],])
```

The output from `top_n` is not ordered according to score as I expected. Compare with using the `order` function

```
 ref      score
1   i 0.71556494
2   p 0.04463846
3   v 0.37290990
4   g 1.53206194
5   f 0.86307107
   ref      score
7    g 1.53206194
10   f 0.86307107
1    i 0.71556494
6    v 0.37290990
4    p 0.04463846
```

The documentation I have read also implies the `top_n` results should be ordered by the specified column, for example

https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: actually the resut is the same but with `top_n` the 5 rows are left in the original order. Try: `df %>% top_n(5) %>% arrange(desc(score))`

Comment: Indeed. `top_n` is equivalent to `filter(x, min_rank(desc(wt)) <= n)`, no ordering of the rows occurs, nor does the documentation suggest it should.

Comment: @Axeman I think the docs do suggest ordering. The cheatsheet linked to in the question states "Select and order top n entries". Typing `?dplyr::top_n` gives
top_n {dplyr} R Documentation
Select top n rows (by value).

Description

This is a convenient wrapper that uses filter and min_rank to select the top n entries in each group, ordered by wt.

Comment: I read the help file as referring to ordering on which the selection takes place, not to rearranging the rows, i.e. `min_rank` is used on `wt`. I agree that the cheatsheet is wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My misunderstanding and expectation was due to my reading of the documentation linked to in the question and described in the comments. Despite some documentation claims, `top_n` does not generated output ordered by `wt`.

Answer (score 1):

Both outputs are the same, but `top_n` is not rearranging the rows.

You can get the same result as `df[order(df$score,decreasing = T)[1:5],]` using `arrange()`

```
top_n(df, 5, score) %>% arrange(desc(score))
```

Flipping the ordering around, `df[order(df$score,decreasing = F)[1:5],]` is equivalent to `top_n(df, -5, score) %>% arrange(score)`.